# Can't find 1.7 JDK after installing it

Tags: java, macos, java-7

I'm trying to update from Java JDK 1.6 to 1.7 and have downloaded the version 7 JDK for mac (I downloaded jdk-7u71-macosx-x64.dmg from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

However after running the installer, which executes, says its installing and copying the files, then indicates the installation was successful I can't find where they have installed to.

I can see the previous version of the jdk is installed at /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk.

But there's no sign of 1.7, nor using spotlight can I find any other .jdk or anything called 1.7.* anywhere on my machine, despite the JDK installer saying it was successful (I've tried running the installer a few times).

If the installer is saying it was installed why can't I find it? Is it supposed to have gone into /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ like the 1.6 one, if so why isn't it and how can I install it when the installer is saying it did so?

[OS X 10.9.5]

Comment: what does java -version in terminal say ?

Comment: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ has it ? not the /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You installed the JDK yourself so it won't be in `/System`.
Try looking in `/Library/Java/...`

You'll need to add this new runtime to your path to get it to work on the command line.

Comment: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home